# Redirecting stdin twice?

Tags: bash, stdin

I have a C program that has a `scanf` call followed by a `read` call. I want to feed both inputs using `printf`.

`printf 10 | program_name` doesn't work for some reason; `scanf` correctly picks up 10, but the `read` call defaults to " " and doesn't even ask for input.

I want to use `printf` twice, once to pass input to `scanf` and the second time to pass input to `read`. How can I do this?

Comment: The scanf is going to consume a lot of the input in its buffer.  In general, it is a bad idea to try to mix printf with write, or scanf with read.

Comment: I didn't write the program, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a terrible hack, you need to ensure that scanf's buffer is full.  Something like:

```
{ printf 10; dd if=/dev/zero bs=4094 count=1;
  echo This text will go to the read if bufsize is 4096; } | program_name
```

The technique here is relying on scanf reading the first 4096 bytes to fill its buffer on its first read, leaving data in the pipe for the read to get.  The main problem is that it is extremely fragile and requires intimate knowledge of the buffering used.  Overall, this is a terrible idea, but not too much worse that calling read after calling scanf on the same file descriptor.

Comment: If the program says `#define BUFSIZE 256`, but the command says `scanf("%d", &length)`, should I use 256 or 4?

Comment: You should use the underlying buffer size, which is unrelated to the macro defined in the program.  It will be system dependent and is probably 4096 or 8192.